# Load Balancing Options on Tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, load-balancing

I have applications running on tomcat, previously standalone.
Now I have to implement high availability for all apps, so here I am.

I have the option of a hardware load balancer or some other means. I will like to know if there are gotchas I have to worry about, especially since I will like to have a single log file location (a single log file between the two application servers I have is preferable).

What do I need to look out for, will multiple file access from the two servers be an issue? Even on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... especially since I will like to have a single log file location (a
>   single log file between the two application servers I have is
>   preferable).

You can do this by using DRBD with a cluster file system ([GFS](http://www.drbd.org/users-guide/ch-gfs.html), [OCFS2](http://www.drbd.org/users-guide/ch-ocfs2.html), ...)

Answer (score 1):

Of course multiple write acces to a file is forbidden on Linux.

You should look for `syslog-ng` (open source edition) as solution for centralized logging.